# Google Earth showing red crosses for embedded images in the KMZ

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

I have generated a KMZ file which contains a few GroundOverlay images (in png). All the images are referenced as relative paths e.g. "files/imageA.png" in the embedded "doc.kml" KML document.

When I opened in Google Earth on my computer, the images were shown as red cross.

Any idea why this occurred? Could it be something configurable in Google Earth to prevent images being shown in the application?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the images actually present in the KMZ file?  Can you provide a link to your KMZ file (or an example one that exhibits the behavior)?

Comment: If you unzip the KMZ into a temporary folder do the images display when opened?

Comment: How are you creating the kmz file? I was doing it wrong at the begining. I was putting all the files in a folder and then creating the zip file and then renaming it to *.kmz. That was wrong. The way it worked for me was making the zip file by selecting all the files and compressed them. Later on I automated the process with python zipfile library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem only occurred on one particular person's computer and that was very random. I don't see any problem with the way the KMZ was created as others were able to open and view it properly. I was wondering it might be to do with the Google Earth configuration/settings on his own computer.